# Is there a way to search your own answers?

Tags: support, search

Say you remember giving an answer on a particular topic but you have answered so many questions it would take a long time to find that answer just by clicking all your answers.  Is there a way to search just your own answers for particular text?

Comment: Select them by putting `user:me` in the query.  Lots more help available by clicking "Advanced search tips".

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48599/how-to-search-my-own-questions-and-answers

Comment: this is definitely not a duplicate of the indicated question.

Answer (score 15):

```
user:me is:answer {search terms}
```

More at [How Do I Search?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)

Answer (score 5):

Use the advanced search:

> is:answer user:me blahblahblah

where blahblahblah is the text

Comment: I cannot make this work. Get zero results. Is this obsolete now ?

Comment: @AAAfarmclub I just tried it on myself and it still work, though I can't say if the results are complete or not.

Comment: is:answer user:me "a" should return any text with an "a" in it, right ? Is there a way to get it to search comments as well ?

Comment: @AAAfarmclub See here, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375445/13295.