# Find an old question I've answered by the content of the question

Tags: support, search

I'm trying to find out an old question I've answered several months ago, but I don't find yet an efficient way for searching. I remember the content of the question, but not my answer and I would like to retrieve my answer.

Is it possible to search (by keywords) **questions I've answered**?

---

Note: [This question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271187/is-there-a-way-to-search-your-own-answers) explains how to search in personal answers (but not how to search in questions to which I have provided an answer) with the following synthax:

```
user:me is:answer {search terms}
```

I want something like

```
iAm:answerer searchIn:question {search terms}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I don't think there is any such search option currently. One option is to use the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/). You may run the [following query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/634497):

```
SELECT q.* 
FROM posts q
JOIN posts a
ON a.parentid = q.id
WHERE a.owneruserid = 309086 
AND q.body LIKE '%search_term%'
```

<sub>Replace the `owneruserid` and *search_term*</sub>

Comment: You don't need the `a.posttypeid = 2`, only answers have a `parentid`.

Comment: Thanks, it works well. As @Tunaki said, `a.posttypeid = 2` seems unnecessary, I've updated your answer!

Answer (score 8):

Use Google: `site:stackoverflow.com your keywords go here`

This usually does it for me, without needing to use SEDE (Stack Exchange Data Explorer).

Comment: adding your name to the search query will generally narrow it down to questions you've asked or answered.

Comment: @Joel: I actually got worse results (poor recall) when I added my SO username to the query