# Can I search questions and answers by string part of comment?

Tags: support, comments, search

There is a Q&A for which the only thing I remember is that a specific user replied to the OP with a comment that contains a specific string. Is there functionality in SO to help me perform this search?

Comment: There isn't much point in trying to use SO functionality when Google can do the job much better.  Use `site:stackoverflow.com` to narrow it down.

Answer (score 2):

Using SO search, you can't.

Basically, [comments aren't indexed for search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183142/ability-to-search-comments-would-be-useful).

You can use SEDE if you feel up to it. In the linked übermeta Q&A a user offered [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/124643/search-keyword-in-user-comments) which you can use as a starting point.